# SOQL query by owners being below in role hierarchy

Tags: soql, role-hierarchy

I have the following role hierarchy

```
CEO
|
|--Big boss
   |
   |--National Manager
      |
      |--Regional Manager
         |
         |--Team Lead
            |
            |--Employee
```

I am free to switch Accounts between Public and Private Sharing Model, ensuring correctly visibility top down.

However, as you can imagine at each level there are multiple branches (multiple Regional, Team Leads etc.), and if we use Public Sharing Model or Public ReadOnly simply saying `give me all accounts` is not good enough -> because we will have accounts returned from different branches.

How can i query `Account` by sth like `Owned by people below $User.Role`

I know that up to 5 levels down i can do a `WHERE (OwnerId = '<ID>' OR Owner.ManagerId = '<ID>' OR Owner.Manager.ManagerId = '<ID>')` but that only works for direct managers, not roles, and only for 5 levels down.

**UPDATE** Ideally, i need this to work in 3 places:

1. Standard LEX list views
2. LWC components (Apex/soql backed)
3. SOQL Rest API

Comment: Do you have Apex available to you? Your post is somewhat lacking in detail as far as what context this logic needs to work from.

Comment: @AdrianLarson i added that info. Basically in 1/3 use cases i do have Apex, but in another 2 not really. I understand that we can pull out the role hierarchy and then just do sth like where `Owner.UserRoleId IN ('')`